# JNDI (in Logback.xml)

Tags: java, logback, jndi

I have the following file:
**Logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <insertFromJNDI scope="context" env-entry-name="java:jboss/properties/mypropertyfile" as="propertyfile" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                ${mypattern1} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I want to reference variables in "mypropertyfile.properties" which is referenced via the *insertFromJNDI* tag.

Inside mypropertyfile.properties are some values:
**mypropertyfile.properties**

```
    mypattern1=AAA
    mypattern2=BBB
    mypattern3=CCC
```

However it cannot find ${mypattern1} (or any) and it says it's undefined.
From the debug logs, I can see it is printing:

```
Setting variable [propertyfile] to [{mypattern1=AAA, mypattern2=BBB, mypattern3=CCC}]
```

and so I know it is reading the file.

But how can I use the variables within this file? If I were to use ${propertyfile} it would print the whole contents of the file.